# Unable to run aliyun-cli in Docker:stable container after installing it. Errors as command not found

Tags: linux, docker, containers, alpine-linux, alibaba-cloud

I am unsure if stack overflow or system fault is the right stack exchange site but I'm going with stack overflow cause the alicloud site posted to add a tag and ask a question here.

So. I'm currently building an image based on Docker:stable, that is an alpine distro, that will have aliyun-cli installed and available for use. However I am getting a weird error of Command Not Found when I'm running it. I have followed the guide here https://partners-intl.aliyun.com/help/doc-detail/139508.htm and moved the aliyun binary to /usr/sbin

Here is my Dockerfile for example

```
FROM docker:stable

RUN apk update && apk add curl

#Install python 3
RUN apk update && apk add python3 py3-pip

#Install AWS Cli

RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade

# Install Aliyun CLI
RUN curl -L -o aliyun-cli.tgz https://aliyuncli.alicdn.com/aliyun-cli-linux-3.0.30-amd64.tgz
RUN tar -xzvf aliyun-cli.tgz
RUN mv aliyun /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/aliyun
RUN rm aliyun-cli.tgz
```

However when i'm running aliyun (which can be auto-completed) I am getting this

```
/ # aliyun 
sh: aliyun: not found
```

I've tried moving it to other bins. Cding into the folder and calling it explicitly but still always getting a command not found. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: The `aliyun-cli-linux-3.0.30-amd64.tgz` binary is not suitable for use with Alpine Linux (not musl-libc compatible). Check out Adiii's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/ellerbrock/alpine-aliyuncli/dockerfile)?

Also why you need to install `aws-cli` in the same image and why you will need to maintain it for your self when AWS provide [managed `aws-cli`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cli-v2-docker-image/) image.

```
docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli --version
```

that's it for aws-cli image,but if you want in existing image then you can try

```
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:2-alpine3.8

LABEL com.frapsoft.maintainer="Maik Ellerbrock" \
      com.frapsoft.version="0.1.0"

ARG SERVICE_USER

ENV SERVICE_USER ${SERVICE_USER:-aliyun}

RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ellerbrock/docker-collection/master/dockerfiles/alpine-aliyuncli/requirements.txt > /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN \
  adduser -s /sbin/nologin -u 1000 -H -D ${SERVICE_USER} && \
  apk add --no-cache build-base && \
  pip install aliyuncli && \
  pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
  apk del build-base && \
  rm -rf /tmp/*

USER ${SERVICE_USER}

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT [ "aliyuncli" ]

CMD        [ "--help" ]
```

build and run

```
docker build -t aliyuncli .
docker run -it --rm aliyuncli
```

output

```
 docker run -it --rm abc aliyuncli
usage: aliyuncli <command> <operation> [options and parameters]
<aliyuncli> the valid command as follows:

batchcompute                                | bsn       
bss                                         | cms       
crm                                         | drds      
ecs                                         | ess       
ft                                          | ocs       
oms                                         | ossadmin  
ram                                         | rds       
risk                                        | slb       
ubsms                                       | yundun
```

Comment: I found a solution and I'll post an answer but generally I would never download some random developer's solution instead of the official way to do it. So just using an after-market solution won't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of lookup I found a github issue in the official aliyun-cli that sort of describes that it is not compatible with alpine linux because of it's not muslc compatible.

Link here: https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli/issues/54

Following the workarounds there I build a multi-stage docker file with the following that simply fixed my issue.

Dockerfile

```
#Build aliyun-cli binary ourselves because of issue
#in alpine https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli/issues/54
FROM golang:1.13-alpine3.11 as cli_builder
RUN apk update && apk add curl git make
RUN mkdir /srv/aliyun
WORKDIR /srv/aliyun
RUN git clone  https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-cli.git
RUN git clone https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-meta.git
ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn

WORKDIR aliyun-cli
RUN make deps; \
    make testdeps; \
    make build;

FROM docker:19

#Install python 3 & jq
RUN apk update && apk add python3 py3-pip python3-dev jq

#Install AWS Cli

RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade

# Install Aliyun CLI from builder
COPY --from=cli_builder /srv/aliyun/aliyun-cli/out/aliyun /usr/bin


RUN aliyun configure set --profile default --mode EcsRamRole --ram-role-name build --region cn-shanghai
```